# How to avoid hard coding the value attribute / inner html of an option within a select menu? For CS50 Finance

Tags: html, flask, jinja2

```html
 <select name="symbol">
    {% for row in stocks %}}
    sym = row["symbol"]
    <option value=sym>sym</option>
    {% endfor %}
 </select>
```

Stocks is a list of dictionaries, 1 dictionary for each stock the user owns. The above is what I have right now, however the issue is that both the inner html of options as well as the value= attribute seem to be hard set to a static string. This is what I mean:

[Image of generated drop down menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spZBn.png)

How would you work around this? I thought about using document id selector to dynamically set the inner html/value attribute and that seems like it would work for 1 single option, but as id is unique, I don't think it would work for future iterations.

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
 <select name="symbol">
    {% for row in stocks %}}
    sym = row["symbol"]
    <option value={{ sym }}>{{ sym }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
 </select>
```

Otherwise, jinja can't know that it has to resolve `sym` and not just display the string "sym".